# .htaccess in a directory makes it disappear from its parent’s listing

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an Apache server running on a linux box (say example.com). Inside the web root is a folder (`http://example.com/docs/`, locally `/home/me/docs`), with an automatically generated index of its subdirectories, enabled by its `.htaccess`:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing NameWidth=* FoldersFirst IgnoreCase SuppressDescription Charset=UTF-8 SuppressHTMLPreamble
```

Now, inside `docs` is `docs/protected`. This subdirectory has its own `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType "Basic"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
#Require valid-user
```

Now, this is where it becomes weird (for me):

- as is, with the commented line, `protected` is not password-protected (which is normal) and is visible on its parent's listing (also expected)
- if I uncomment the `Require valid-user`, `protected` becomes password-protected (if I type the URL directly), but it also doesn't appear on its parent's listing any more.

Anyone can figure out what could cause that?

---

**Edit:** now I notice that if I type the URL of the protected directory, then enter the password, then go back to the listing without closing the browser, the listing is complete. In summary, the directory is hidden until I have given credentials to it. But I only want to protect its content, not its existence!

---

PS: This is with Apache/2.2.21 running on a Synology box.

Comment: is there anything in the `${sitename}-error` log?

Comment: @Zypher no, nothing in the logs

Comment: I updated the question: `protected` directory now is accessible (I was missing an `AuthName`) but still doesn't show up on parent listing

Answer (score 3):

And the answer is that the parent directory should have:

```
IndexOptions ShowForbidden
```

I lost two hours finding that.